# deleting /bin entries in linux

Tags: linux, shell, yum

I have installed CentOS. I want to remove bzip2, so I enter this command in the shell:

```
yum remove bzip2 bzip2-libs
```

Then nearly 500 packages were removed and I can't enter any command. For example:

```
ls 
-bash: /bin/ls no such file or directory
```

How can I re-install the lost packages?

Comment: .... *facepalm*

Comment: and you were not warned about so many pacages were to be uninstalled? bzip2 is needed by very many other packages, so I don't see a point in uninstalling it...

Comment: it staggers the mind that you ever thought removing bzip2 was necessary, the program is like 30k?

Comment: I really want to favorite this one, but I'm afraid I'd be accused of Schadenfreude.  Woe the dilemma!

Answer (score 9):

Trying to recover the system will probably take you several hours. I recommend just reinstalling.

Comment: +1, when I ran an indirect dependency check on my system it just kept on scrolling my terminal which means that removing bzip2 is about the most effective way to uninstall a ton of packages. Figuring out all the packages that were removed in the process, as well as getting them all back, is probably non-feasible. Maybe a log still mentions all their names, but then still, I support reinstalling...

Comment: forget the fork bomb!!!   just uninstall bzip2.... CRASH!   Mwahahah!!

Comment: @lornix: It's the new `rm -rf`, I think unmerging things from the system profile should also be preserved unless `--no-preserve-root` is passed to the package manager.

Comment: have to introduce the `-i-know-what-im-doing-honest-really-i-do-let-me-do-this-shuddup` option... just to be sure.

Comment: @lornix: when you try to do something like that in the `aptitude` (text) UI, then a dialog pops up, asking you to enter the exact phrase "Yes, I am aware this is a very bad idea" before continuing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It is a part of `coreutils`. Install that

Comment: hopefully `yum` itself is still present...

Comment: @glglgl: `python` needs `bzip2-libs`. `yum` needs `python`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Badabam. SO a fresh install will probably be pending...

Comment: no!!!! honestly when I try to install coreutils server said 
/usr/bin/yum: no such file or direcotory

Comment: @glglgl: Even better, `rpm-libs` also needs `bzip2-libs`. Fun times ahead!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeehaw. Hopefully, it wasn't a production system...

Comment: Won't help, he lost a ton of packages. Even when you have `coreutils` there is still a long road ahead...

Comment: As soon as you at least manage to install `rpm` and stuff, it should be feasible. And if you do that from a Live CentOS, you (nearly) can do whatever you want, if you set the right install target paths. But that's still a PITA.